# C# WebApi - Json serialize bring a property to higher level

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, webapi

I have a class with following structure

```
class Model
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public Dictionary<string, List<ComplexType>> Values {get;set;}
}
```

utilized in an Dotnetcore webApi project and returned from my controller as the following object

```
Ok(new List<Model>() { 
new Model{
  Id = 1,
  Values = new Dictionary<string, List<ComplexType>>() { {"Item1", new List<ComplexType>()} }
} } )
```

which would produce Json output as :

```
[
     {
         "Id": "1"
         "Values": {
           "Item1": [{}]
          }
     }
]
```

So my question is any way possible, to bring the Dictionary property name to a higher level in output Json structure. 
Basically Omitting the property name "Values" in "Model" class and merging lower object so it would look something like this:

```
[
     {
         "Id": "1"
         "Item1": [{}]
     }
]
```

Comment: why don't you just remove values property all together and make Model a dictionary

Comment: @Steve  that would mean I have to move the `Id` property inside the `ComplexType`. I need to have that particular property at same level, ultimately getting the Json output as I require

Comment: Acually you are right, If I add `Id` as a property in Dictionary itself it could work. But that would also mean `Id` should have value type same as `Item1`, where as it is supposed to be `int` type, could workaround with dynamic or object type etc.. Still want to try out if possible to retain the former way

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that Value property all together and make Model a dictionary type

```
class Model : Dictionary<string, List<ComplexType>> 
{
     public int Id { get; set; } 
}
```

then you can just do

```
var model = new Model();
model.Id = 123;
model["Item1"] = new List<ComplexType>();
```

Comment: Yes after your previous comment, I did try that but two issues, it is not serializing Id from webapi response and getting Sonar warning related to "update implementation to conform ISerializable pattern".. will figure out the latter but former itself not happening...

Comment: @JagatSingh not sure what serializer you are using. but json.net should be able to handle it just fine. I believe you can set the serializer for web api. don't remember the exact procedure on top of my head

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own serializer, its simpler then you think and you'll have way more control on generated json.

```
class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<ComplexType>> Values { get; set; }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return
            $"{{" +
            $"\"{nameof(Id)}\":\"{Id}\"," +
            string.Join(",", Values.Select(x => $"\"{x.Key}\":" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x.Value))) +
            $"}}";
    }
}
```

Then call it like this -

```
var json = "[" + string.Join(",", obj.Select(x => x.ToJson())) + "]";
```

Finally return the above json as response.

```
var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```